# passing character arrays to a function

Tags: c++

```
void PrintPosition (int *,int *,char* arrayLine);
```

This is my prototype function before int main().

```
char arrayLine[71]="----------------------------------------------------------------------";
PrintPosition (&Tortoise,&Hare,&arrayLine[]);
```

This is my int main() where I want pass down arrayLine[71] to a function called PrintPosition.

```
 void PrintPosition (int *Tortoise, int *Hare, char *arrayLine)
    {
    char arrayLine[71]="----------------------------------------------------------------------";

    if(*Tortoise==*Hare)
    {
        arrayLine[*Tortoise+0]='O';
        arrayLine[*Tortoise+1]='U';
        arrayLine[*Tortoise+2]='C';
        arrayLine[*Tortoise+3]='H';
    }
    else 
    {
        arrayLine[*Tortoise]='T';
        arrayLine[*Hare]='H';

    }

    cout<<arrayLine<<endl;



}
```

This obviously doesn't compile at all.

What I am intending to do here, is to pass down the whole character array with size 71 to function, then manipulate char array at the function.

The reason why I am trying this is because I get stack frame error, buffer overrun error, stack around the variable 'arrayLine' was corrupted error. <---when I just declared arrayLine[71] in the function without passing through it.

So the question is, what is the possible method for me to pass down the whole array as I intended?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a question here.

Comment: To solve the problem with stack corruption [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005760/stack-around-the-variable-arrayline-was-corrupted)

Comment: Besides the obvious invalid method of passing an array by-address and the redefinition of `arrayLine` as a local variable, both of which are clearly spelled out by the compiler error messages, the *caller* side of this from `main`, including the setup of `Tortoise` and `Hare`, are somewhat important and should be included in your code list. But more important, I'm curious how you get a stack frame error in code that doesn't even *compile*, much less *run*.

Comment: I have no clue. I sent these codes to someone I know (he runs Linux) and he told me he had no error message at all....

Comment: @user3543568 Why are you declaring `arrayLine` again in the function?  Does it make sense to you to pass `arrayLine`, and then, as if the function needs convincing, declare it again?

Comment: so it is best to take out arrayLine="-------------" in the function right?

Comment: @user3543568 - You're passing `arrayLine` to the function.  That function is now supposed to take the passed-in `arrayLine` and do whatever it needs to do, not create a brand new `arrayLine`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to pass the array to the function is:

```
PrintPosition (&Tortoise,&Hare,arrayLine);
```

This is a *pass by pointer* (with slightly confusing syntax). It is not possible to pass a C-style array by value.

To pass an array by value you would have to use a different sort of array, such as `std::array`. Using C-style arrays in C++ is discouraged because they do not behave like values.

Of course, you should remove the definition of `arrayLine` within `PrintPosition` .

Comment: Note that making this change won't fix your stack corruption problem

Comment: I am really lost here. I've been struggling with this for 4 hours now.

Comment: FIx your stack corruption first, as described in the other thread. It was better before you try passing `arrayLine` as a function parameter, that is a bad idea.